# Efficiently generating time index of pre-transcribed speech using it's audio source and open source tools

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, transcription

On TED.com they have transcriptions and they go to the appropriate section of the video when clicking a part of the transcription.

I want to do this for 80 hours of audios and transcriptions I have, on Linux with OSS.

This is the approach I'm thinking:

1. Start small with a 30 minuite sample
2. Split the audio up into 2 minute WAV file formatted chunks, even if it breaks words up
3. Run the phrase spotter from CMU Sphinx's long-audio-aligner on each chunk, with the transcript
4. Take the time index for identified words/phrases found in each bit and calculate the actual estimated time of the ngrams in the original audio file.

Does this seem like an efficient approach? Has anyone actually done this?

Are there alternate approaches that are worth trying like dumb word counting that may be accurate enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can just feed all your audio and text in a long audio aligner and it will give you the timestamps of the words. Using this timestamps you can jump to the specific word in a file.

I'm not sure why do you want to split your audio or do something else.

Comment: From the comments I judged it was not useful on longer samples.

Comment: Is there a reliable audio aligner (e.g for hour long audio's and transcripts) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you judged from which comments but long audio aligner is supposed to be reliable. If it's not this issue can be fixed.

Comment: I was going by: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/08/long-audio-alignment-phrase-spotter-and-the-subsequent-improvements/ but I suppose I'll find out! Once I finally get it to install.